# What's the purpose of varchar(0)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I recently encountered a problem caused by a typo in the database creation script, whereby a column in the database was created as `varchar(0)` instead of `varchar(20)`.

I expected that I would have gotten an error for 0-length string field, but I didn't.  What is the purpose of `varchar(0)` or `char(0)` as I wouldn't be able to store any data in this column anyway.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO This specific case was mysql - updating the question.

Comment: Why do you assume it has to be useful to be legal?

Comment: @Wooble I didn't ask anything about legal. Clearly, it's legal. I'm asking what the purpose of this is.

Comment: MySQL is known for being non-compliant with SQL standards.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not allowed per the [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) standard, but permitted in MySQL. From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html):

> MySQL permits you to create a column of type `CHAR(0)`. This is useful primarily when you have to be compliant with old applications that depend on the existence of a column but that do not actually use its value. `CHAR(0)` is also quite nice when you need a column that can take only two values: A column that is defined as `CHAR(0)` NULL occupies only one bit and can take only the values `NULL` and `''` (the empty string).

Answer (score 6):

Just checked MySQL, it's true that it allows zero-length CHAR and VARCHAR.

Not that it can be extremely useful but I can think of a situation when you truncate a column to 0 length when you no longer need it but you don't want to break existing code that writes something there. Anything you assign to a 0-length column will be truncated and a warning issued, but warnings are not errors, they don't break anything.

Comment: then why not to delete that column? I think deleting the column may required to change in application's code...

Comment: I already told "you don't want to break existing code that writes something there"

Comment: I had same guess so I + your answer, I think add this line in your answer if you wish.

Comment: Rather that allow it, it just throws a warning and truncate the value depending on your SQL mode.

Answer (score 3):

As they're similar types, `char` and `varchar`, I'm going to venture to guess that the use-case of `varchar(0)` is the same as `char(0)`.

From the documentation of [String Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html):

> MySQL permits you to create a column of type CHAR(0). This is useful
>   primarily when you have to be compliant with old applications that
>   depend on the existence of a column but that do not actually use its
>   value. CHAR(0) is also quite nice when you need a column that can take
>   only two values: A column that is defined as CHAR(0) NULL occupies
>   only one bit and can take only the values NULL and '' (the empty
>   string).

Answer (score 0):

It's useful in combination with a unique index for if you want to mark one specific row in your table (for instance, because it serves as a default). The unique index ensures that all other rows have to be `null`, so you can always retrieve the row by that column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to store boolean values.

Look this code:

```
mysql> create table chartest(a char(0));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.26 sec)

mysql> insert into chartest value(NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into chartest value('');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'true' from chartest where a is null;
+------+
| true |
+------+
| true |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'false' from chartest where a is not null;
+-------+
| false |
+-------+
| false |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

We can use `NULL` to represent true and '' (empty string) to represent `false`!

According to MySQL reference manual, only `NULL` occupies one bit.

Answer (score 0):

One other reason you might end up with `VARCHAR(0)` is if you're loading data from a CSV with `LOAD DATA INFILE` and your script parses the CSV for field sizes to provision a new MySQL table according to the size of the data.

You could skip columns that have no data, but if you want to accurately represent the CSV in MySQL, then it would be most efficient to set empty fields to zero length.