# What use has mysql data type 'BINARY(0)'?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

Right now I'm trying to learn the details of MySQL. The type BINARY needs as many storage bytes as provided via its parameter, so for example, if I define a column as BINARY(8) it consumes 8 bytes.

On the site https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings, there is a table mapping the types to their storage requirements. And it says that I can define a BINARY(0). But in my opinion, it does not make sense. BINARY(0) would mean that I can store 0 bytes - so nothing. Do I miss a thing? What use does it have? Or what is the reason for that?

On the other hand, I cannot define a bigger BINARY-column than one with 255 bytes. I always thought the reason for 255 is that you start counting at 0. But when you don't need a BINARY(0) you could define a BINARY(256) without problems...

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one post.

Comment: Keep in mind the column can be nullable.

Comment: Related: [whats-the-purpose-of-varchar0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555485/whats-the-purpose-of-varchar0)

Comment: *"I cannot define a bigger BINARY-column than one with 255 bytes."* If you need bigger simply use `BLOB` (65,535 bytes max) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to poke around on this one, because I didn't know myself.  From [this link](https://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/data-types/binary), we can see that `BINARY(0)` can store two types of values:

- NULL
- empty string

So, you could use a `BINARY(0)` column much in the same way you would use a non nullable `BIT(1)` column, namely as a true/false or yes/no column.  However, the storage requirement of `BINARY(0)` is just one bit, which requires no additional storage beyond the boundary for nullable columns.

Since the non `NULL` state of the `BINARY(0)` column would be empty string, which translates to zero, you could find all such records using:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE bin_zero_column = 0;
```

The unmarked `NULL` records could find found using `WHERE bin_zero_column IS NULL`.

Comment: `BIT(1)` can be `0`, `1` or `NULL`. Also you didn't mention the theoretical storage size of `0` bytes for `BINARY(0)`.

Comment: Hmm .... if you can distinguish between `NULL` and `''`, then it is impossible for the storage cost to be zero.  It requires at least one bit of state on physical storage to represent NULL versus `''`.  (If not, then we have the basis for a *magical* compression mechanism that can represent data with zero storage ... using lots of `BINARY(0)` columns.)

Comment: @StephenC I'm not a SQL expert, but I do understand that sometimes a `NULL` entry in a column such as `VARCHAR(50)` will take up no space.  So, the required one logical bit of storage (as you correctly point out) might not always be needed.

Comment: Tim - I'm not a database expert either.  But this is basic information theory.

Comment: @StephenC `NULL` itself has its own storage in InnoDB.  So, by using `BINARY(0)`, though it may take up space, it may not take up any _additional_ space, whereas `BIT(1)` would.

Comment: Yes ... but that's not what you said in your answer :-)

Comment: It isn't the fact of whether a column *is null* in a row that consumes the 1 bit, it's whether it *is nullable*. A nullable column has one bit allocated per row to indicate whether it is null in that row, so each 8 nullable columns require 1 byte of storage per row to store the flag of whether the column is null.  A nullable `BINARY(0)` thus consumes 1 bit of storage per row but as long as this doesn't push you past the next mod 8 boundary of the number of nullable columns, it rides for free, because rows consume storage in whole bytes, not bits.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: So I can optimize my database by saving 1 Byte using a `BINARY(0)`. I think that's cool, inspite I admit the effect is around 0.1%... :-) 
But: Does this mean, that a `BIT(1)` takes a whole byte additional storage? (you said, rows consume storage in whole bytes - does this apply to columns, too?)

Comment: @armin.miedl I *believe* the specifics of `BIT` are at the discretion of the storage engine, where InnoDB stores each column separately in an integral number of bytes, but MyISAM packs them together.

Comment: In InnoDB, I think there is a length field in the row for each column.  This is a 1- or 2- byte value, one bit of which is dedicated to NULLness.  This implies that `BIT(1)` and `BINARY(0)` take at least _one byte_.  But, as armin points out, the cost of that 1 byte is quite insignificant.

Comment: If you have dozens of two-state columns, then consider using `SET` or `INT UNSIGNED` to hold a bunch of them in a single column.  This adds complexity to your code, but lets you test multiple flags simultaneously (in some cases).